# I don't know what is wrong with my code

Tags: linux, shell, unix

```
#!/bin/sh

read -p "Input a file or directory what you want " x

for FILENAME in `ls`

do

if [ -e $FILENAME ]

then
        echo "File exist" #if file exist, you should show me that is it a directory
# or symboliclink ...for so on  like that
elif [ -d $FILENAME ]
then
        echo " It is a directory"

elif [ -L $FILENAME ]
then
        echo " It is a symbolic link"

elif [ -c $FILENAME ]
then
        echo " It is a character tool file"

elif [ -b $FILENAME ]
then
        echo " It is a block tool"

elif [ -p $FILENAME ]
then
        echo " It is a pipe "

elif [ -S $FILENAME ]
then
        echo " It is a socket"

elif [ -f $FILENAME ]
then
        echo " It is a ordinary file"

else
        echo " file isn`t exist"

fi

done
```

The error message is

```
./fn: line 43: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
./fn: line 48: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: ' = apostrophe, ` = backtick. "Isn't" needs an apostrophe, not a backtick.

Answer (score 4):

You are using a backquote instead of an apostrophe in `echo "file isn't exist"`. If you really want to use the wrong character there, you need to escape it to prevent the shell from interpreting it as the beginning of a command substitution:

```
echo "file isn\`t exist"
```

---

The error message isn't particularly clear, since it uses a backquote to simulate an opening single quotes. The *intent* is an ASCII rendering of something like

> ./fn: line 43: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ‘`’

but the end result is just a bit confusing.